# Python: printing a line if a certain line comes after it

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, skip

Lets say I have a .txt file which reads

```
this is line x  
this is line y  
this is line x 
this is line x  
this is line x  
this is line y   
this is line x  
this is line x  
this is line y
```

I want to print 'this is line x' only if 'this is line y' comes after it (so in this example it should only print 3 times).

I've tried:

```
skip_line = True  
with open("input_n.txt","r") as myfile:
     for line in myfile:
        if "x" in line:
            skip_line = False
        elif "y" in line:
            skip_line = True
        else:
            pass
        if skip_line:
            continue
        print(line)
```

However this prints every 'this is line x' anyway I can see in my code that it does this because I do skip_line = false for x in the string, so how can I make it print the three times I actually want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track the previous line with your bool. Save it with another var.

```
skip_line = True
prev_line = ""
with open("f.txt","r") as myfile:
    skip_line = True
    for line in myfile:
        if "x" in line:
            next_skip_line = False
        elif "y" in line:
            next_skip_line = True

        # skip_line is False if the last line was x
        # next_skip_line is True if this line was y
        if not skip_line and next_skip_line:
            print(prev_line)
        prev_line = line
        skip_line = next_skip_line
```

Comment: So I tried using this for my actual file (where 'this is string x' is actually multiple (17) lines of text) and It ended up still writing the slab of multiple lines more times than the occurance of string y

Comment: I'll make an edit. I changed the condition to hopefully make it slightly more clear.

Comment: You didn't need an else: pass, you can simply drop that else.
The new longer if statement really reads If the last line was an x and this line is an y, though the use of the two variables. Since the line you want to print is the previous one, I've also saved that each time through the loop.

Comment: So lets say I want to print all the lines between x and y but only if its x, some lines, then y as opposed to x, some lines, x, some lines, y. How would I implement that in this code?

Comment: okay, I'd make a list like "mylist = []", 
then for my if statement, if I see an x, I'd set a flag to true and reset the list to [],
if I see a y and my flag is true, I print mylist if it is not empty, reset the list, set the flag to false.
for anything else, if my flag is true, I push that line to mylist using mylist.append.

Answer (score 0):

```
#using a list to dummy the txt file read line by line
lst = [
    "this is line x",  
    "this is line y",  
    "this is line x", 
    "this is line x",  
    "this is line x",  
    "this is line y",   
    "this is line x",  
    "this is line x",  
    "this is line y"
]

store = ""
for line in lst:
    if "y" in line and store:
        print(store)
    elif "x" in line:
        store = line
```

With this, it will only print if the current line contains `"y"` and a previous line exists.